# Magento, PayPal, and PayPal IPN - no event fired when an order is successfully placed

Tags: magento, paypal-ipn

My module needs to know when a success checkout has occurred. So, in accordance with what I have read in various places, I listen out for the events checkout_onepage_controller_success_action and checkout_multipage_controller_success_action. That's fine, when I pay with a dummy credit card on my dev site, one of the above events is fired. But I wondered what happens if I pay with PayPal, so I said up a PayPal dev sandbox to test it out. Examining the http traffic, I saw that a notify_url was sent to PayPal when the order was placed. That was promising - when the paypal/ipn action is called from PayPal, the PayPal module will, if a 'completed' status is received, fire the checkout _xxx_controller_success_action - right? Wrong.

My module relies on knowing when an order is successfully placed, so I am looking for advice on the best way to tackle this issue please.

I'll just add a little bit about my environment here in case it is relevant.
I am running Magento 1.4.2.0 on my laptop. When using PayPal Standard, a notify_url is sent to PayPal which overrides any set up in the PayPal account. I am testing from my laptop, so the notify URL passed to PayPal is not accessible from the PayPal sandbox. So I changed the notify_url to point to an accessible JSP that just printed out the notification it received. I then give that parameter string to a little Java program I run on my machine which posts it to the original notify_url (.../index.php/paypal/ipn).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but still a relevant question. We successfully used event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action (which is used by Magento core GoogleAnalytics extension) to observe successful PayPal Express orders (and also checkout onepage orders). Event sales_order_payment_pay did NOT fire for new orders.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble - try using the `sales_order_payment_pay` event instead - it worked nicely for me